# Traduction du nom de ce département universitaire spécifique?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique, terminologie

J'ai traduit

> *Faculty of Automatic Control and Computers, Computer Science Department*

par

> *Faculté d'Automatique et Ordinateurs, le Département Science des Ordinateurs*.

Est-ce correct ?

Comment: Pourquoi les votes négatifs, mon question aussi, sans aucun explication ? Nous avons un terroriste ici :p.  J'essayerais de réparer un peu (+1), mais je n'ai pas encore la réputation exigée.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Je propose

> Faculté d'automatique et d'informatique, département informatique.

(J'ai traduit les deux *Computers* et *Computer science* par *informatique*.)

Answer (score 6):

There exists a *National Institute for Computer Science and Control* translated with *Institut national de recherche en informatique et automatique*.

*Computer science* translates as *informatique* (see IATE).

Hence a possible translation: “Faculté de recherche en informatique et automatique, département d'informatique”.

Comment: If we drop "recherche" (it's a Faculty, not an Institute), we have the response of [Impair](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/6529/2243).

Comment: True, only I quoted my source. And yes, you can drop "recherche" and simply translate with "Faculté d'informatique et automatique, Département d'informatique."

Answer (score 2):

Je traduirais *Computer Science Department* par *département d'informatique*, ou si on veut insister sur *science*, par *département de recherche en informatique*.

Pour *Faculty of Automatic Control and Computers*, je traduirais par *faculté d'automatique et d'informatique*. En France, une qualification habituelle mais qui couvre plus de domaines, est *sciences pour l'ingénieur*.

Ça pourrait donner quelque chose comme: *faculté de sciences pour l'ingénieur, département d'informatique*.

Comment: Il y a été aussi un "_Département des sciences de l'ingénieur_" (en français) et il y a plusieurs sciences de l'ingénieur: électronique, électrotechnique, métallurgie, transportation (?), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Je propose:

> Faculté d'automatique et d'informatique, département des Sciences de l'informatique.

Answer (score 0):

C'est la faculté qui contient le département, non pas le contraire me semble-t-il.
Du coup, on dirait plutôt quelque chose comme « Faculté des sciences, département informatique et automatisation »...

---

*Après réexamen de la question suite aux autres réponses :*
Une recherche google sur l'étrange expression **faculté d'automatique** renvoie une énorme proportion de résultats liés à des étudiants roumains, et je vois que toi aussi, Liviu, tu es roumain. Est-ce un cursus spécifique de l'école polytechnique de Bucarest? Du coup, pourquoi ne pas s'inspirer de [ceci](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%C3%A9_Politehnica_%28Bucarest%29) et opter pour **Faculté d'automatique et d'informatique** (Automatică si Calculatoare) ?

Comment: Je veux que la translation signifie quelque chose, aussi proche que possible (?), pour un Français, pas pour un Roumain. J'ai besoin d'un CV internationale :)

Comment: De plus, il y a aussi la Faculté de mathématique et d'informatique, encadre dans l'[Université de Bucarest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Bucharest).